# lookup hashtable returning blank result

Tags: .net, powershell

Trying to use this PowerShell script to find an email address based on a portion of the filename. I'm able to parse out the portion needed (i.e. if I output `$ext` it displays the extension number) but the resulting variable I'm trying to store the email address in comes out blank.

```
$Path = 'c:\test2'
$delim = '-'
# table for extensions & associated email addresses
$extensions = @{
    'bob@test.com'  = '23';
    'jack@test.com' = '1000';
    'blah@test.com' = '765'
}

Get-ChildItem $Path -Name | foreach {
    $nameArray = $_.Split($delim)
    $newName = $nameArray[2] + " " + ($nameArray[0].Substring(0, 8))
    $ext = $nameArray[3]
    $emailAddress = $extensions[$ext]
    Write-Output $newName
    Write-Output $emailAddress
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have your keys & values backwards in your hashtable.  Another note: the pipe `|` is a natural line-continuation so you don't need to escape `\`` the newline.

Comment: Weird, I had the values in the other direction before and got the same result. Maybe I forgot to add the ' ' around the values. That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, keys in hashtables can be objects, not just strings, so you'd need to either ensure the key or your accessor are the same types.